# What is default compress number for jpg2000 when exporting?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, image, jpg, jpeg-2000

I have a file geodatabase that has 635 GB Imagery I copied from Mosaic Dataset. I am trying to export it to jpg2000 to a new file geodatabase. I am thinking what is the default compress number for jpg2000 when I export it ?

I thought it was 75 percent so I calculate it would compressed to about 158 GB ? Am I correct ?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 SP3

Comment: The value is not a percent but "quality value/level".  The higher the quality value, the lower the compression (and thus the greater the file size) will be.  If you want maximum compression, use a lower quality value, but note that the quality of the compressed image will decrease (you will get more compression artifacts).

Comment: Luke, so what value do you suggest is the best number to use rather than having artifacts when you compression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your first question I found confirmation of the default compression quality (number) on the help page entitled **[Compression (Environment setting)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000020000000)** where it says (with my bolding):

> If JPEG, JPEG_YCbCr, or **JPEG 2000** is selected, you can also set the
>   compression quality to control how much loss the image will be
>   subjected to by the compression algorithm. The values of the pixels of
>   an image compressed with a higher compression quality will be closer
>   to those of the original image. Valid value ranges of compression
>   quality are from 1 to 100. The **default compression quality is 75**.
>   If you don't explicitly set a value, the default will be used.